# getting IE,Opera,Firefox and chrome to recognise a sound format

Tags: html, flash

I have audio placed into a controller on a page, however when i load different browsers the sound files are either no even seen by the browser or they dont work. Ive converted the files to wav. which apparently works universally for IE,Opera, Firefox and Chrome, however changing the file format does not change this situation. I know it has something to do with HTML audio tag or something but I am still unsure

```
<embed src="../Sounds/home_page_readout.wma" width="405" hidden="false" height="39"   pluginspage="../Plugin/niftyplayer.fla" autoplay="false" controller="true"></embed>
```

Comment: You need to have files in multiple formats to support all browsers.  What is your current markup?

Comment: No, I mean copy and paste your current markup and/or code into your question.

Comment: There we go ive put the code in for you to see i dunno if this is what you want , its the file name and the controller and all tha tstuff i think

Comment: I'm not sure why you tagged HTML5 since you're not using HTML5 `audio` anywhere, so I removed it, also there's no Java in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [w3schools HTML5 audio element page](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp):

> Currently, there are 3 supported file formats for the  element: MP3, Wav, and Ogg:

```
Browser             MP3 Wav Ogg
Internet Explorer 9 YES NO  NO
Firefox 4.0         NO  YES YES
Google Chrome 6     YES YES YES
Apple Safari 5      YES YES NO
Opera 10.6          NO  YES YES
```

The listed solution is to provide the file in multiple formats:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ive seen this but im kinda unclear, where it says "controls" does that field need to be changed to what ever id you give it ? and where it says song that will be the file name of the song ??. An by doing this would i have multiple controllers on my page or does it just apply the file formats to that controller, and im also guessing if i had multiple controller on a page id do this for each controllers. Also does the "type" field need changing,. Sorry about me being a complete noob id just like to understand what it is that im actually doing, instead of just mindless copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on *which controller* you deploy the answer is different. But I'm pretty sure that your problem isn't about the file format and you should check weather different browsers can find the file or not.

As a general answer, I prefet to use some tested solutions for embedding audio in web pages like Niftyplayer:

https://github.com/progrium/niftyplayer

Comment: ok this is weird now when i run my pages the play button doesnt budge its colour shade has changed that it looks like something is being played but nothing is actually being played, its like that for all the controllers on my different pages, ive checked the autoplay parameter and its set to false and i do have a file attached to it, ive link the plug in url to one of the ones on the site and still nothing it doesnt actually change .

Comment: this  means that there is an error accessing the path (the url of your sound file)

Comment: well ive just tried manually changing the url of the file name with the proper path name. The button is now unstuck but when i press play still nothing happens